# Placing a block element a link inline with form elements

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a search where you can dynamically add criteria.

I'm using Bootstrap and this is how it looks so far (HTML rendered)

[image]

The problem is that I want the plus and minus links to display at the end of each line of criteria like so:

[image]

My Code:

```
 a.addremove{
   display:block;
  background-color: #4B5E75;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  font-size:16px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 38px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}


  <form class="span10 offset1 custom-form">    
      <div class="control-group">
          <div class="controls">
              <select class="field">
                 <!-- <option disabled selected>Choose a Field</option>-->
                  <option value="title">Title</option>
                  <option value="lo">Learning Objectives</option>
                  <option value="unit">Unit</option>
                  <option value="cal_year">Calendar Year</option>
                  <option value="year">Year</option>
                  <option value="theme">Theme</option>
                  <option value="type">Type</option>
                  <option value="person">Person</option>
             </select>

           <select>
                  <option value="contains">Is</option>
                  <option value="lo">Is Not</option>
                  <option value="Includes">Includes</option>
                  <option value="Excludes">Excludes</option>
             </select>

            <span class="value">
             <input type="text"  placeholder="Keyword">
             </span>

             <a class="ss-icon addremove add">add</a>
          </div>

  <div class="control-group">
          <div class="controls">
     ........
```

What's the best way to achieve that while retaining the block level circular styling i have going on for those links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `display: block;` use `display: inline-block;`

Comment: Thanks. I thought I tried this! obviously not. Should have known.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
a.addremove{
   display:block;
  float:left;
  background-color: #4B5E75;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  font-size:16px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 38px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: That puts it at the beginning of the line, before the input fields. I suppose I could do it by making each line position:absolute and then  making the a absolute (right:0..) but it feels wrong

Answer (score 0):

make the element display inline-block;

```
a.addremove{
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top; /* or middle */
      background-color: #4B5E75;
      color: #fff;
      margin: 0;
      width: 32px;
      height: 32px;
      font-size:16px;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 38px;
      border-radius: 50%;
}
```